# How to send parameters from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to use a RequestDispatcher to send parameters from a servlet.

Here is my servlet code:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

 String station = request.getParameter("station");
 String insDate = request.getParameter("insDate");

 //test line
 String test = "/response2.jsp?myStation=5";

 RequestDispatcher rd;
 if (station.isEmpty()) {
     rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/response1.jsp");

 } else {
     rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(test);
 }

 rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

Here is my jsp, with the code to read the value - however it shows null.

```
    <h1>response 2</h1>
    <p>
        <%=request.getAttribute("myStation")  %>
    </p>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
Greener

Comment: RequestDispatcher is not used to read parameters. Hence I've edited your post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your servlet use [request.setAttribute](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) in the following manner

```
request.setAttribute("myStation", value);
```

where value happens to be the object you want to read later.

and extract it later in a different servlet/jsp using [request.getAttribute](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) as

```
String value = (String)request.getAttribute("myStation")
```

or

```
<%= request.getAttribute("myStation")%>
```

Do note that the scope of usage of get/setAttribute is limited in nature - attributes are reset between requests. If you intend to store values for longer, you should use the session or application context, or better a database.

Attributes are different from parameters, in that the client never sets attributes. Attributes are more or less used by developers to transfer state from one servlet/JSP to another. So you should use [getParameter](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) (there is no setParameter) to extract data from a request, set attributes if needed using setAttribute, forward the request internally using RequestDispatcher and extract the attributes using getAttribute.

Comment: Thank for the extensive comments. 
I really appreciate. 
The passed values have a page scope, so I think the method you showed me would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use [getParameter()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)). An attribute is set and read internally within the application.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,
      String test = "/response2.jsp?myStation=5";

You are adding myStation=5  as query string.As the query string parameters are stored 
   as request parameters in Request Object.

Therefore you can use ,

It  works fine.Thanks.