# I have retrieved information from a database, but how do I format it properly? Perhaps using html

Tags: servlets, html-table, resultset

I have retrieved information from a database through a servlet and I am able to print it using the same servlet (on web page using tomcat). But in order to format it nicely (perhaps like a table), I will probably have to use html. Can someone please help me on how to do this? Perhaps pass the values to a html page and display it like that? Thanks :)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class PersonalInfoOutput extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            boolean st = false;
            try { 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select FirstName, LastName, Address from payroll_system.employee_info where employeeID = 1234"); 
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
                st = rs.next(); 
                if(st){

                out.println(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                out.println(rs.getString("LastName"));
                out.println(rs.getString("Address"));

                }
             }catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @Manu Thanks, but how do I pass the values from servlet?  (FirstName, LastName, Address?

Comment: write it to the response object

Comment: @Reinard Can you please help me with that :) Sorry, I'm still learning. I'm a high school software student.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407076/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-servlet